# Statisticsのダウンロードとインストールを行いmean()を実行したらMethodErrorがでます

Tags: julia

使用言語はjuliaでバージョンは1.6.3です。
書籍の通りにコードを書いて実行しているのですがMethodErrorがでてしまい解決方法がわかりません。

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("Statistics")
```

でパッケージをダウンロード、インストールしました。その後

```
using Statistics
mean([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

を実行したら

```
MethodError: no method matching mean(::Vector{Int64})
Closest candidates are:
  mean(::Any, !Matched::Any) at c:\Users\~\Julia勉強\benkyou1.ipynb:1
```

となりました。
何が問題でどう解決したらいいのかわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

意味が分かりませんが、出力を全てリセットしてVSCodeを立ち上げ直したうえで実行しなおしたら普通に動きました。